# Enable rc-local service in CentOS 8.X

Tags: centos, systemd

I'm trying to enable rc.local in CentOS 8.1, the service file exists by default, but I can't enable it:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl enable rc-local
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a special unit that goes by point number 3:

> 3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
>      D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).

So you don't `systemctl enable` it. You enable it by making `rc.local` file executable, as is on non-SystemD systems.

Can be verified with `systemctl cat rc-local`. Take note of `ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/rc.d/rc.local`.

So as is usual with `rc.local`, place your commands in `/etc/rc.local` (symlink to `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`) and make the file executable via `chmod +x`, to have this "service" enabled/run at boot time.

Comment: **note** that `/etc/rc.local` != `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` at least in CentOS 8, in case you're used to `/etc/rc.local`.